# We need program that remove all rows with values in cell 6 like 2,3,4,5 and so on from column F1 and do not remove value 1?

Tags: excel, vba

**We need program that remove all rows with values in cell 6  like 2,3,4,5 and so on  from column F1 and leave only rows with value 1 and heard of table top first row? Also we need leave fist row intact with table heard.why this code work wrong beacause it does not remove 10 100 and only remove 2,3,4,5 and so on.**

```
 Sub RemoveRows1()
    
     ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.ClearFormats
    Dim m As Long
    
    m = 1
  Do While m <= ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("F1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count  
    If not InStr(1, Thisworkbook.Activesheet.cells(m,6).value = 1) > 0 Then 
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(m, 6).EntireRow.Delete

    
        Else
            m = m + 1
        End If
    
    Loop
    End Sub
```

Comment: Better put some of your sample data with expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that great big `if` in the loop, just use

```
If not InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(m, 6).Text, "1", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then 
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(m, 6).EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

And that will delete the entire row of anything where column F doesn't contain 1.

Comment: Have to vote for this, just a neat application of instead of looking for what you don't want (the OP), you look for and keep what you do want.

Comment: Also we need leave fist row intact with table heard.

Comment: why this code work wrong beacause it does not remove 10 100 and only remove 2,3,4,5 and so on.

Comment: @petercook to leave the first row intact, start with `m=2` not `m=1` so the loop doesn't look at the first row

Comment: "10" and "100" both contain a 1, so it will leave them in. If you only want the value 1 then replace `Instr(1, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(m, 6).Text, "1", vbTextCompare) > 0` with `Thisworkbook.Activesheet.cells(m,6).value = 1` - this will look for cells with nothing but '1' in them (anything with other words etc will get deleted)

Comment: And it's not generally considered good practice to edit the question according to an answer and then change the question - the answers lose their relevance. If you have a problem with an answer, ask the answerer to edit it or add comments.

Comment: how can we train the program do not delete heard of the table with value of cell Кратность?

Comment: @petercook to avoid a specific cell (as you said with value Кратность) just add it into the `If not` statement - `If not Thisworkbook.Activesheet.cells(m,6).value = 1 or Thisworkbook.Activesheet.cells(m,6).value = Кратность Then`. However I have no experience working with non-latin characters (is that russian there?) so can't guarantee it will work.

Comment: It loops forever because of something wrong with the `Do While` line. Try `Do While m <= Thisworkbook.activesheet.usedrange.rows.count`

Comment: Please upvote the comments if they are useful to you.

Comment: @petercook Try asking that as a separate question, I think.